# Measure gRPC bandwidth per stream

Tags: go, grpc, prometheus

I have a [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) service written in Go which has very long running streams. I want a way to measure the network/bandwidth usage per stream and make that information available to [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

I found [`grpc.StreamServerInterceptor`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StreamServerInterceptor) but from what I gather, it doesn't give you access to the marshalled message (which I need to figure out the size).

There's [this](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus) third party middleware I've found, but it doesn't seem to export any network related information.

Comment: `StreamServerInterceptor` doesn't give you access to the marshalled message, it gives you access to the stream. You could easily proxy the stream and count the bytes as they go by.

Comment: @Adrian I'll go with an external proxy if I have to, but I'd much prefer to export the network usage with the rest of the server's metrics.

Comment: Not an external proxy, an internal [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Comment: @Adrian how can I "count the bytes" if I'm proxying a stream of unmarshalled messages?

Comment: I just found the proto.Size method. I'll be marshalling twice, but I'm going to worry about that until it becomes a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a [`stats.Handler`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#Handler) on both gRPC [servers](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StatsHandler) and [clients](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithStatsHandler). You can put whatever labels you need in the context you provide it with.

gRPC will then invoke your handler's `HandleRPC` method with either a [`stats.OutPayload`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#OutPayload) or a [`stats.InPayload`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats#InPayload), containing the message (raw and encoded), its uncompressed and wire lengths and a timestamp.

It's [all in the source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/091a800143380a06a4721749da705ccbf4ae5e7a/stream.go#L726).

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: I need a way to figure out which stream the payload is coming from. I figure I need to tag the context somehow, but I don't see where to do that.

Comment: Your `stats.Handler`'s `TagConn` and `TagRPC` methods *should* get called with information on the connection and respectively RPC. You should place the bits that are relevant to you into the `Context` that you return and that `Context` (or one based on it) should be passed along in the `HandleConn` and `HandleRPC` method calls your handler gets.

Comment: It would be cool if the `TagRPC` parameters contained the request message.

Comment: `HandleRPC` will provide you with the message. `TagRPC` is intended to provide the metadata, e.g. what method this is.

Comment: Yes, but I need the message from the `InPayload` (which identifies the stream) when handing the `OutPayload` (to know which metric to update).

Comment: Sorry, not actually a user of gRPC, was just browsing the code base. :o)

From the documentation (and bits of code) it would seem that your handler should get its `TagConn` method called (providing you with local and remote addresses to place into the `Context`); then `TagRPC`, providing you with the method name (to place into the `Context` again); and finally `HandleRPC`, with a `Context` that contains all keys you placed into it in the previous 2 calls.

Comment: I remember having seen a gRPC issue report that something or other wasn't working with a specific transport (don't remember which one), and the answer was that they were not implemented yet. So if your `Handler` isn't getting all these calls, then it could be that. But you should be able to easily implement them, and have the patch accepted, if this is the case. ;o)